# Performance issue in Applying join on dates for selecting data by day in cumulative way

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote one query to fetch reporting data, it is fetching data for give time range, but now facing performance issue in the query i have analysed the problem and problem is when we apply join on date it is taking too long time, i am putting my query below which is taking 10 sec. if you have alternate which can give better result please provide.

```
SELECT 
 dtbl.selected_date AS grouping,
 if(def.dfID IS NULL, 0, datediff(DATE(dtbl.selected_date), DATE(CONVERT_TZ(def.createdDate, "+00:00", "-05:00")))) AS defectAge,
if(def.dfID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS DefectCount
1
FROM
(SELECT selected_date
FROM
(SELECT adddate('2020-02-02', t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date
FROM
(SELECT 0 t0
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) t0,

(SELECT 0 t1
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) t1,

(SELECT 0 t2
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) t2,

(SELECT 0 t3
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) t3,

(SELECT 0 t4
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE DATE(selected_date) BETWEEN '2020-02-02' AND '2020-03-02') dtbl
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT d.dfID,
d.createdDate,
d.lastStatusChangeDate,
drs.defaultresolutionstatusID
FROM defect d
LEFT JOIN listDetail ld ON ld.listDetailID=d.dfType
LEFT JOIN listDetail ld1 ON ld1.listDetailID=d.priority
JOIN project p ON p.projectID = d.projectID
LEFT JOIN defaultresolutionstatus drs ON drs.listDetailID=d.dfStatus
AND drs.projectID = d.projectID
WHERE p.clientID = 51
AND d.projectID IN (4179)
        AND d.extentityDataID is null
        AND if('-1'='-1', true, d.affectedRelease in (-1))
AND if("-1"="-1", TRUE, ld.listValue IN (-1))
AND if("-1"="-1", TRUE, ld1.listValue IN (-1)) ) AS def ON DATE(dtbl.selected_date) >= def.createdDate ;
```

Comment: Specify your MySQL version... and you really need in 100k dates (over 270 years)?

Comment: Post your plan output too

Comment: Make a calendar table.

Comment: i need to fetch based on user input which is wide, i am not sure what input user will provide so i am just selecting range from whole 270 year which is very efficient it is not taking much time, as soon as i reduce the time range time of query execution is getting decreased.

Comment: I'm impressed that you have 270 years worth of data. Anyway, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @strawberry we can reduce that span of year but for me that is not important for a while

Comment: @Nick i have tried using calender table as well but it has same performance, what i am suspecting is ON DATE(dtbl.selected_date) >= def.createdDate  this code is creating issue.

Comment: @ArjunPrajapati if the value in `dtbl` is already a date then you don't need to use the `DATE` function on it. I find it hard to believe that a pre-built calendar table with dates in it (and an index on them) is not significantly faster than all the calls you have to `adddate` in your derived table.

Comment: @Nick that query was never a performance bottleneck, that query is providing result quickly the issue is when we join that table with other table it is creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

- `AND  if("-1"="-1", TRUE, ld1.listValue IN (-1)) ) AS def` -- Don't clutter the query with no-ops; construct the `WHERE` clause dynamically in application code.
- `ON DATE(dtbl.selected_date ) >= def.createdDate` -- If the datatype is `DATE`, then there is no need to use `DATE()`.
- `CONVERT_TZ...` -- If the timezone is set correctly, you may not need to covert on the fly.  Also, consider `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATE`.
- MariaDB has a nifty "sequence table" that lets you generate a sequence of numbers (and, hence, dates) on the fly -- much faster than what you are doing.
- What is `... AS DefectCount 1 FROM ...`?  Maybe a typo?
- What version of MySQL?  If it is not-very-new, then this construct perform *terribly*:  `FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  Even with a newer version, checking every date (a long list) against a limited range of data may be the main performance problem.
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, it may provide more clues.
- What indexed do you have?